# Sending Client hint headers to API server

Tags: client-hints

It seems with the ClientHint API being newer, there isn't a lot of information available on this topic.  I've read dozens of articles and, at this point, I'm missing some key details in the implementation requirements.

Here is the scenario.  We have many frontend apps that make GraphQL requests (POST) to our API server.  This server is hosted on a different domain than our frontend apps.

Through my research, I'm seeing that using the `meta` tag for `delegate-ch`, I should be able to delegate the client hint headers to the API server domain, like so:

```html
<meta
      http-equiv="delegate-ch"
      content="sec-ch-ua http://api.foo.test; sec-ch-ua-model http://api.foo.test; sec-ch-ua-platform http://api.foo.test; sec-ch-ua-platform-version http://api.foo.test; sec-ch-ua-mobile http://api.foo.test"
/>
```

Unfortunately, that's not working.  I've tried adding the `accept-ch` `meta` tag as well, but I believe that's unnecessary.  I've also tried appending the `/graphql` path to the urls, as that's the actual path for GraphQL API requests.  None of that helps.

Additionally, our API server is returning the `Accept-Ch` and `Critical-Ch` response headers on OPTIONS requests (all requests for that matter).  I understand this may not working since this isn't the origination domain.  Would be great if it respected it though.

So, is this a POST request issue?  What's the issue here?  We're at a point now where `User-Agent` headers are frozen and no longer reliable.

This is being tested on Chrome 116 which should have full support and no privacy settings modifications that I'm aware of.  I have also been able to confirm that the headers are being passed on other sites with GET requests where the response headers are requesting it - using this same Chrome instance.

Answer (score 0):

Someone is surely going to come across this post with the lack of information available.  After much digging and reading on the spec, the issue is that the client hint headers are only sent with `https` requests.  This is obvious as it's a privacy consideration.  Unfortunately, that means you're going to have to support `https` in your dev environment if you want to get any reasonable testing done.

`POST` requests are supported as well.

Ultimately, you have to either delegate the headers using a `meta` tag on the original domain executing the requests (`delegate-ch`).  Or include `Permissions-Policy` response header on the same domain authorizing and suggesting the headers be sent to the defined domains with the request.

https://web.dev/migrate-to-ua-ch/#strategy-delegating-hints-to-cross-origin-requests

If you're making API requests, like is the case for us, you probably don't need to include any headers on the actual API server.  The headers are tied to the request/response with the frontend application.  The `Permissions-Policy` or the `delegate-ch` meta tag, tell the browser which domains/servers to share these headers with.

We ended up going with headers instead of a `meta` tag, as that gives us better control with regards to frontend devs breaking the implementation requirements.